# UPS Rates API gives low price

Tags: php, xml, api, ups

I have a PHP/XML script to get rate quotes from UPS. I've set it up according to the UPS Rates documentation and it seems to work, but the prices I get are consistently lower (by 10-20%) than what I get if I login to UPS and enter the same info/service etc.
Without putting the whole XML request here, I am passing:

Shipper postal, country, account number
Shipto postal, country
shipfrom postal, country
Service code
Payment Information - prepaid
Packagingtype code
Dimensions - length, width, height
weight

Has anyone seen this and figured out a solution? I'm guessing there's a parameter that defaults differently on the UPS site from the API, but I can't find it.

Comment: Link to documentation? Are you setting correct currency or country details(source/destination)?

Comment: @web-nomad thanks for your reply. The API docs are here: https://www.ups.com/upsdeveloperkit/downloadresource?loc=en_US but you have to be logged in with a UPS account to access them. It's returning the correct currency (USD).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had this same problem.  A little testing showed I wasn't specifying the pickup type in my request, and I believe it was defaulting to "01" (Daily Pickup).  When I specified a pickup type of "03" (Customer Counter), the values returned from the API matched the website exactly.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<RatingServiceSelectionRequest xml:lang="en-US">
  <Request>
    <RequestAction>Rate</RequestAction>
    <RequestOption>Shop</RequestOption>
  </Request>
  <PickupType>      <-- Make sure you are
    <Code>03</Code> <-- specifying the
  </PickupType>     <-- pickup type
  <Shipment>
    ...
  </Shipment>
</RatingServiceSelectionRequest>
```

Download the documentation from [here](https://www.ups.com/gec/techdocs/pdf/Rates_Pkg_Gnd.zip), and reference **Rating Package - XML Developers Guide.pdf** in the ZIP.

Comment: tried this now 2020, did increase value returned by XML rate script but still much lower than UPS calculator output, not sure what's the difference yet. Seems may be fuel surcharge that is supposedly included. Noting for RequestionOption set from Shop to Rate shows only 1 response. Also not sure if user type matters, mine is Personal and trying both test/prod has same result.

Comment: I think I got it, in the RATE XML docs shows the grouping of the XML "nodes" in my case the Dimensions had to be a child of package, I also supplied the unit of measurement code(which may be default already) and I got the same value from calc. Also supplied residential address indicator(in my case).